# How to change container view size with animation when embedded view size is changed?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout, containers

I'm trying to the below scenarios.
1. container have a embedded view.
2. Once height of embedded view is changed with animation,
3. With animation, Container height is also changed as same as height of embedded view.

I have already tried "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false"

It's working.. Container view size is changed when embedded view size is changed.
However, Container height is changed without animation.

Is there any proper way to update container view size with animation when embedded view size is updated?

Comment: Same proble. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove container width/height constraints and leave only width/height constraints of the embedded view. So, embedded view will set height/width of the container. 
Then you can animated embedded view height constraint and container height also will be changed animated.

UI looks like this:
black it's container, pink it's embedded view
[image]

**EDITED**

if you're working without constraints, you can animate your content via CGAffineTransform. If you scale you containerView, embedded views also will be scaled

code looks like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `top, bottom, leading and trailing` `constraints` of the `innerView` with the `outerView`. Also, add a `height` `constraint` to the `innerView`.

[image]

Now animate the `height` `constraint` of the `innerView` like,

```
self.innerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 60.0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

[image]